# want to hide "ansible_facts": { "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3" } from ping module output?

Tags: python, configuration, ansible, ansible-facts

I want to hide `"ansible_facts": { "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"}` from the output of ping module.

Comment: Can you give us some example code, etc?

Comment: This is related to Ansible ping module

Answer (score 3):

Just add the following to ansible.cfg:

```
interpreter_python = /usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to configure [DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-stdout-callback) and *`" Set the main callback used to display Ansible output."`*. For example

```
$ cat playbook.yml
- hosts: test_01
  tasks:
    - ping:

$ export ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=actionable; ansible-playbook playbook.yml
PLAY [test_01] ***

PLAY RECAP ***
test_01: ok=2  changed=0  unreachable=0  failed=0  skipped=0  rescued=0  ignored=0
```

See other available [callback plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html#plugin-list).

Comment: Nope... This is not suitable for custom callback plugins.